# Java first time using keybindings, Keybinding events arent being registered on the JPanel

Tags: java, swing

As the title states this is the first time i am using keybinds in an Java application, in fact this is the first time i have heard of them. I can get my game to work using KeyListener but when i use a CardLayout to switch from my menu to the game i ran into all sorts of focusing problem.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {


    private final String RENDER = "render";


    public GameFrame(){


        this.setTitle("Snake By Chris Edwards");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(805, 700);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel render = new JPanel();

        render.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT), "left");
        render.getActionMap().put("left", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        });
        render.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.VK_UP), "up");
        render.getActionMap().put("up", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        });
        render.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT), "right");
        render.getActionMap().put("right", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        });
        render.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN), "down");
        render.getActionMap().put("down", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        });

        this.add(render);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new GameFrame();
    }
}
```

The Render panel paints as expected, but none of the key strokes are being registered, e.g. "test" is never printed to the console.

Can anybody see what i am doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Exactly, your "test" program above is terrible for our purposes as it contains much distracting non-compilable and completely irrelevant code. Simplify, simplify.

Comment: Don't forget the imports too. And have you tested this code above before posting it? Are you 100% sure that it compiles? With the implements statement? Where is the main method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your KeyStrokes incorrectly:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
```

You should use:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong InputMap.  Change

```
render.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(
```

to

```
render.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
```

and same for the others.

And in the future, please please don't force us to go through a ton of unrelated uncompilable code. That's not very fair to us volunteers, and only makes it much more difficult for us and for you to test and correct the code. Remember: Always test new concepts **in isolation**.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

   private static final String LEFT = "Left";
   private static final String UP = "Up";
   private final String RENDER = "render";

   public GameFrame() {

      this.setTitle("Snake By Chris Edwards");
      this.setVisible(true);
      this.setSize(805, 700);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      JPanel render = new JPanel();

      render.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), LEFT);
      render.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), LEFT);
      render.getActionMap().put(LEFT, new AbstractAction() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(LEFT);
         }
      });
      render.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), UP);
      render.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), UP);
      render.getActionMap().put(UP, new AbstractAction() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(UP);
         }
      });

      this.add(render);

   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new GameFrame();
   }
}
```

Comment: I just put extra in to show what components they are etc, i am sorry. Also this is in isolation i have put in in a separate test project, and i have tried you solution prior to asking, i have tried all of the JComponent.XXXXXXX variations.

Comment: @chrisedwards: camickr is (of course) correct as well. Your getKeyStroke is wrong. You would do well to check out the examples of key bindings to be found on this site before creating your own.

Comment: +1, @chrisedwards, the "WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW" is the safest to use when you are using a CardLayout as it implies you will be swapping panels, so it you forget to place focus on the panel it should still work, although the "WHEN_FOCUSED" will work if you make sure you use the requestFocusInWIndow() method when you swap the panel.

Comment: @chrisedwards: for example